# SvG element in a page transulated with google transulator script error is thrown

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

I am using the SVG element in a page and when transulating the page to german language I am facing the following script error in console.

[image]

> error: "Uncaught TypeError: a[b].target.className.indexOf is not a
>   function"

have anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's related to having Google Translation Extension installed in Chrome together with SVG elements. There's a [really good comment on GitHub](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/1134#issuecomment-565808141) to why this error happens.

#### TL;DR

SVG's are of type `SVGElement` and the `className` property is an instance of `SVGAnimatedString` which doesn't have the `indexOf()` function. There's currently no known fix for the Google Translation + SVG scenario.