# Tracking down "className.indexOf "javascript error

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser

We are getting a couple of users who are getting long list of these errors being caught by the global onerror handler:

```
TypeError: a[b].target.className.indexOf is not a function. (In 'a[b].target.className.indexOf(Zb)
```

Nothing appears broken in my app. I looked at all my code and all my libraries and `className` only appears in a couple places and `className.indexOf` doesn't appear at all.

In addition, the line number reported is "401", and since this is a Vue app, there aren't anywhere near that number of lines in any file that we deliver!

So, I think it must be caused by a browser extension but I'd like to be sure. Is there a way to figure out what the trigger for this is?

(Both of those users where the error occurred were using Chrome 84)

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_element_classname  Seems like it would have to be a super old browser to not support className

Comment: This was Chrome 84 on iOS.

Comment: Probably the same problem as [stackoverflow.com/questions/59867102](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867102/svg-element-in-a-page-transulated-with-google-transulator-script-error-is-thrown) and [target-classname-indexof-is-not-a-function-at-least-not-mine](https://medium.com/@amir.harel/a-b-target-classname-indexof-is-not-a-function-at-least-not-mine-8e52f7be64ca)

Comment: Thanks for the links! That does look like the same issue. If you had made this an answer instead of a comment I'd mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modifying your onError handler to print the source

`window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) { ... };`

looks like you are only printing the message

Comment: Yes, that is the statement I use. The problem is that the source for this particular problem is reported as the html page. Which doesn't have close to 401 lines.

Comment: In that case, I would remove the `window.onerror` check on browser and it will bre reported as `VM:xxx` you can then track down the source.